# Fire event in another process

Tags: c#, events, ipc, multiprocess

In my application I'd like to start another process, which has 3 events. How can I fire/trigger an event, or just call a function, which is in another process? 
I also would like to pass some object to the another process (i.e. the handler of my form's textbox).

[This example looks perfect](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14791/NET-Remoting-with-an-easy-example), but can I do that without tcp? Ie.: over pipes, etc..
Correct me if I wrong, but the eventwaithandle is not a solution for me, because every
(3) event would require on own thread to block.

Thank you in advance,

Daniel

Comment: You can use the Windows API to send messages directly to controls.. what sort of things are you looking to trigger in the other application?

Comment: You can binary serialize your object and store it in a queue. But then your other process will have to monitor queue and fire the events. But I don't think, you can fire events from different process.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but still...

There are some ways to accomplish something similar with [REDIS](http://redis.io/) in a PUB/SUB manner. One of the most popular .Net implementations is [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis).

[HERE](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/RedisPubSub) is an usage example.